# MSBuild throws AggregateException in WPF on OpenSolutionAsync()

Tags: c#, wpf, msbuild, roslyn

I'm loading a solution at runtime using MSBuild like that:

```
    private Solution LoadSolution(string solutionPath) {
        var msw = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
        var solution = msw.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result;
        return solution;
    }
```

This works when I tried it in a console application however it throws an `AggregateException` when I try to run it in a WPF application which references the console application in which the `LoadSolution` method is located.

I tried doing it with async/await but whenever I do that I never receive a result from the thread.

The error I receive states :

First exception :

```
One or more errors occurred.
```

Inner exception :

```
{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
```

Framework version 4.5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution mentioned in [GitHub Roslyn issue tracker](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4127), to install [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis v1.0.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/1.0.0) worked for me. I tried to execute the code mentioned in the question on .NET 4.5.2 console application.